# Concatenating text in an ASP.NET localized label

Tags: asp.net, localization

Trying to localize text in ASP.NET labels... want to add a ':' after the localized text.  I could just add the ':' to the localized text in the resource file, but that seems silly... there should be an easy way to do this.

`<asp:Label id="RoleTypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:  GS3, RoleTypeLabel %>:' AssociatedControlID="RoleTypeDropDown"></asp:Label>`

(note the ':' at the end of Text='...')

Of course, this doesn't work... and neither does anything I can think of to concatenate a ':' onto the end of the localized text.

Anyone know how to do it?

TIA,
James

Comment: Did you try concatenating the escape sequence for a colon, which is &#59; ?

Comment: I'll have to give that a try, I'm curious to see if it works

Comment: No dice... as soon as I add anything after the <%$ ... %> the page literally displays <%$ ... %>.  But thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've always put the colon outside the label.

```
<asp:Label ID="RoleTypeLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: GS3, 
RoleTypeLabel %> />:
```

Comment: Duh!  Of course!  I was putting it between the opening and closing asp:Label, and it was ignoring it.  

Thinking too complicated when there's a simple solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, the only issue I run into is with the padding on the control... I can't have any right-padding on the label, or it pushes the ':' away from the text.  But I need an even amount of padding after the colon.  Hmm, I'll have to think about that for a bit.

Comment: True - I generally use a <span> around the entire label and the colon in order to apply any styles that are required.

Comment: The span helps, but I had a lot of pain trying to get the text to align... the colon appears either too high up or subscripted.  I've tried all combinations of vertical-aligns, but I have to have the right combination of aligns on the label, the colon span, and the textbox to the right.  I have it in the right spot, but it took a little voodoo, and if I change padding, margins, or font sizes, I'm back to shuffling aligns.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you put ':' into the resource file?

Comment: The primary reason is that you may re-use the term in a context where a colon is not required (such as a column header).

Answer (score 1):

You could also append the colon using CSS if your labels are positioned appropriately.

```
label:after
{
    content: ':';
}
```

Comment: That's a cool approach... though I'd probably assign a class to the label so I could only append it to labels that need a ':'

Comment: That's fine, too. The magic is in the `:after` pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into a similar situation as I went back and localized one of our apps. Ended up using a Literal control inside the Label:

```
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="txt" CssClass="class" ID="lbl" runat="server">
    * <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Words, labelText %>" />:
</asp:Label>
```

We were using some CSS to right align form labels with a fixed width so any text outside of the label actually broke our pages. The accepted answer is most straight forward, but might not work in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the colon as part of the string that you mean to translate. See [#3 in this 12 Commandments of Software Localization article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/12-commandments-software-localization/), which explains that punctuation often needs to be translated. For example, French adds a space before the colon, and languages like Arminian or Greek may use a different symbol in the colon's place.

As for [reusing terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961411/concatenating-text-in-an-asp-net-localized-label#comment3027067_2961554), consider that "Due:" and "Due" are different enough linguistically that you're better of translating them individually.